# Movie ended on JMF,now terminate program

Tags: java, video-processing, jmf, system.exit

I want my program to terminate itself once the movie played has ended,
using system.exit(0).

is there a way of doing that?

I dont want to use Timer.

Comment: Got it!                                       player.addControllerListener(new ControllerListener() {
                                    public void controllerUpdate(ControllerEvent e) {
                                 if (e instanceof EndOfMediaEvent) {
             System.exit(0);
                                                  }
                                            }
                                                  }

Comment: Would you mind posting your answer below so we can get this off the Unanswered list?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

```
    player.addControllerListener(new ControllerListener()

    { 

      public void controllerUpdate(ControllerEvent e) 

      {   

      if (e instanceof EndOfMediaEvent) 

        {   

        System.exit(0); 

        }

      } 

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP posted this answer as a comment.

```
 player.addControllerListener(new ControllerListener() {
     public void controllerUpdate(ControllerEvent e) { 
        if (e instanceof EndOfMediaEvent) { 
            System.exit(0); 
        }
     }
 }
```